# WP PageNavi not accepting CSS file

Tags: css, wordpress, pagination

I recently added plugin WP PageNavi to our website. The plugin itself works well, but it refuses to obey the CSS styling provided in pagenavi-css.css

Web runs latest wordpress and DIVI theme (child theme). Elegant themes (DIVI developers) states, that this plugin is fully compatible with their products, but something is wrong.

Things I tried:

-enhanced child theme's navigation.php with this code

```
<?php if (function_exists('wp-pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); } else { ?><div class="navigation">
    <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
    <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
</div><?php } ?>
```

-coppied modified pagenavi-css.css to child theme's directory, content:

```
.wp-pagenavi {
    clear: both;

}

.wp-pagenavi a, .wp-pagenavi span {
    border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    margin: 2px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: small;
}

.wp-pagenavi a:hover, .wp-pagenavi span.current {
    color: #ff0000;
}

.wp-pagenavi span.current {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: medium;

}
```

But still, no formatting appeared on the website (apart of red colour, which is wrong anyway). A live example can be viewed here: https://azub.eu/community/blog/

Could anyone, please, advice me, where am I wrong or why is the styling missing? 
Thx

**EDIT:
Looks like Autoptimize has something to do with it**, but I excluded pagenavi-css.css from optimizing. But the general css optimization is still ON. Any gues?
[Screen from Dev tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s82FG.jpg)

**EDIT 2:** So after disabling Autoptimize, devtools already shows the source of styling as pagenavi-css.css [dev tools screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf4AX.jpg) **BUT** the style is still not there! Any thoughts?

EDIT 3: Today, I was looking onto a plugin conflict and turned all plugins OFF and ON and suddenly the CSS kicked in. But when I tried to update the CSS it is stuck again. I also performed the same steps that lead to a positive result the first time, but without any luck. Now it looks like this [current look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBJww.png).
Any thought where could the CSS be held by WordPress?

Comment: I see your border is not working?? What exactly it should look like?

Comment: Are you using any cache plugin? clear the cache and check.

Comment: we use Autoptimise (excluded pagenavi-css.css from optimising) and WP Super cache (it's cache is empty in time of testing) 
The border element is just added for testing purpose because it's not responding to any modification at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid to say that you have to use `!important` in your **CSS** because your current theme is using `!important CSS` in its **default behaviour**. So do one thing, just replace it with this.

```
.wp-pagenavi {
    clear: both;

}

.wp-pagenavi a, .wp-pagenavi span {
    border: 1px solid #BFBFBF !important;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    margin: 2px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: small;
}

.wp-pagenavi a:hover, .wp-pagenavi span.current {
    color: #ff0000;
}

.wp-pagenavi span.current {
    font-weight: bold !important;
    font-size: medium !important;

}
```

Comment: replaced the code, cleared Autoptimize cache, cleared browser cache but still doesn't work

Comment: your code is not replaced .. replace the code with my given code.

Comment: /*domain*/web/www/wp-content/themes/Divi-child-theme-01/pagenavi-css.css

Comment: But it is not updating.. I don't see !important css added there

Comment: I also tried to replace the default css file at /*domain*/web/www/wp-content/plugins/wp-pagenavi ; cleared all possible cache I know of, but still the same result. I upload the modified files via Filezilla so it should be updated correctly.

Comment: Maybe you not updating the correct files. Try  incognito mode of chrome(cntrl + shft + N)

Comment: I think the file is correct. This source also describes it: https://www.isitwp.com/wp-pagenavi-styling/
Looks like Autoptimize might be causing the trouble. Edited the original post...

Comment: I think Auto-optimize is causing the problem .. you have to disable it for once and run the site then enable it.

Comment: I tried to disable Autoptimize, then uploaded the css again and tried it. The source of CSS was already listed as pagenavi-css.css but it didn't work anyway :( ... Any other thought what might it be? - See EDIT2 of main post

Comment: Can't help you beyond this as I need to check the code to see the exact thing going on ..

Answer (score 0):

So, in my case what helped was to turn off every single plugin, then switch the theme to some default and then to turn everything back on. After these actions, CSS kicked in.
It was DIVI and cache combination problem.